# Reading data from excel and rewriting it with a new column PYTHON

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I recently managed to create a program the reads data from excel, edit it and rewrite it along with new columns and it works good, but the issue is the performance if the excel file contains 1000 rows it finishes in less than 2 mins but if it contains 10-15k rows, it can take 3-4 hours and the more I have rows the more it becomes exponentially slower which doesnt make sense for me.

My code:

Reading from xls excel:

```
 def xls_to_dict(workbook_url):
        workbook_dict = {}
        book = xlrd.open_workbook(workbook_url)
        sheets = book.sheets()
        for sheet in sheets:
            workbook_dict[sheet.name] = {}
            columns = sheet.row_values(0)
            rows = []
            for row_index in range(1, sheet.nrows):
                row = sheet.row_values(row_index)
                rows.append(row)
            return rows
        return workbook_dict

data = xls_to_dict(filename)
```

Writing in the excel:

```
rb = open_workbook(filename, formatting_info=True)
r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
wb = copy(rb)
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
```

I read and found a package called Pandas that reads xlsx and tried working on it, but failed to access the data from the DataFrame to be a dictionary. So couldn't edit it and rewrite it to compare the performance.

My code:

```
fee = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

My input row data file is:

ID. NAME. FAMILY. DOB Country Description

My output file is:
ID. NAME. FAMILY. DOB Country ModifiedDescription NATIONALITY

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Try timing the read and the save to see where the slowdown is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove iterating over rows by converting sheet data to a dataframe and get values as list.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def xls_to_dict(workbook_url):
    xl = pd.ExcelFile(workbook_url)   
    workbook_dict = {}
    for sheet in xl.sheet_names:      
        df = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet) 
        columns = df.columns          
        rows = df.values.tolist()     
        workbook_dict[sheet] = rows
    return workbook_dict,columns

data,columns = xls_to_dict(filename)
```

for saving also you can remove for loop by using a dataframe

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(filename) 
sheet_name = xl.sheet_names[0] #sheet by index
df = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name)
df["DOB"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DOB"])
df["age"] = df["DOB"].apply(lambda x: abs(relativedelta(datetime.today(),x).years))
df["nationality"] = #logic to calculate nationality 

book = load_workbook(filename)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name)
writer.save()
```

Comment: thanks, but how to add a new column and rewrite the old columns along with the new column in the sheet

Comment: what is the logic of new column?

Comment: one is calculating the age from the DOB, and one check the nationality from the country of birth.

Comment: Thanks for the update, its giving me an error on the load_workbook function, it says it doesnt exist. Also, I am wondering how can I make the logic using df? I have to loop on the data to check which country, etc. I did that and I have the data in a dictionary called citizenship but I dont know how to connect it the df

Comment: @SMH i have added calculation of age and relative imports,nationality calculation should write by yourself according to the data structure.I cant reproduce the example without data.

Comment: thanks @Rajith . I am wondering if I have a function that translates a cell, will I use:
df["translateddisc"] = df["description"].apply(lambda x: (translator.translate(x)) or how will it work? Also there is a function that detects the language, will I say:  df["detected_lang"] = df["description"].apply(lambda x: (detect(x))?

Comment: to translate and detect language,if you are familiar with NLP,you can call google natural language api inside the lambda function for each row value and get the translation and language (gcp nlp api gives around 70000 requests per month for free) .also there are separate libraries for detect language as well you can try out.check this https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/

Comment: I've added those new lines: df["Name and country"]  = df[['Country','Name']].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
    df["Translation"] = df["Description"].apply(lambda x: (translator.translate(x)))
    df["Detected Language"] = df["Description"].apply(lambda x:detect(x)). how can I write them in the excel after processing?

But it gives me an error while trying to write them back to the excel again, it is not happy with     book = load_workbook(filename).

Comment: saving is same as mentioned in the answer,df is sheet data and  after modified the df,it will add to excel as same sheet name. please check  relevant packages are installed and imported correctly.file names are correctly pointed to the location.